# Keyboard Focus Not working in Pywinauto

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

The left part of the screen shot shows the windows that I am trying to automate, and the right part of the screenshot is the Inspect tool of Microsoft.
[image]

I am using  Pywinauto 0.6.1 on Python 3.5.2 using the Anaconda Distribution on my Win 10-x64 machine. This is my Code:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application, WindowSpecification
from pywinauto.controls.uiawrapper import UIAWrapper
#
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title = 'Scanner: PravinsSignalAPP')
dlg_spec = app.window(title='Scanner: PravinsSignalAPP')
dlg1 = WindowSpecification.child_window(dlg_spec, title="ctlScanner")
dlg2 = WindowSpecification.child_window(dlg1, title="DataGridView")
dlg3 = WindowSpecification.child_window(dlg2, title="Row 0")
dlg4 = WindowSpecification.child_window(dlg3, title="Trade Time Row 0", control_type="DataItem")
#
#UIAWrapper.set_focus(dlg_spec)
UIAWrapper.set_focus(dlg4)
```

When I try to execute this I get the following error:

```
"ElementNotFoundError: {'top_level_only': False, 'title': 'ctlScanner', 'backend': 'uia', 'parent': <pywinauto.uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo object at 0x000001AE6CE31E48>}"
```

I am able to setfocus on dlg_spec. My doubt is - How do I set Focus on dlg4 ?

And this is the output of print (dlg_spec.print_control_identifiers()) :

```html
Control Identifiers:

Dialog - 'Scanner: PravinsSignalAPP'    (L-8, T-8, R1928, B1058)
['Dialog', 'Scanner: PravinsSignalAPP', 'Scanner: PravinsSignalAPPDialog']
child_window(title="Scanner: PravinsSignalAPP", auto_id="frmPopoutChart", control_type="Window")
   | 
   | Pane - ''    (L0, T23, R1920, B1050)
   | ['', 'Pane0', 'Pane', 'Pane1', '1', '0']
   | child_window(auto_id="ctlScanner", control_type="Pane")
   |    | 
   |    | Table - 'DataGridView'    (L0, T198, R1920, B1049)
   |    | ['DataGridView', 'DataGridViewTable', 'Table']
   |    | child_window(title="DataGridView", auto_id="grdResults", control_type="Table")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Custom - 'Top Row'    (L0, T198, R1919, B219)
   |    |    | ['Custom1', 'Top RowCustom', 'Custom0', 'Top Row', 'Custom']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Top Row", control_type="Custom")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Header - 'Trade Time'    (L1, T198, R101, B219)
   |    |    |    | ['Header', 'Header1', 'Header0', 'Trade TimeHeader', 'Trade Time']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Trade Time", control_type="Header")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Header - 'Symbol'    (L101, T198, R201, B219)
   |    |    |    | ['SymbolHeader', 'Symbol', 'Header2']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Symbol", control_type="Header")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Header - 'Last'    (L201, T198, R301, B219)
   |    |    |    | ['Header3', 'Last', 'LastHeader']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Last", control_type="Header")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Header - 'Volume'    (L301, T198, R401, B219)
   |    |    |    | ['Volume', 'VolumeHeader', 'Header4']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Volume", control_type="Header")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Header - 'Alert Time'    (L401, T198, R501, B219)
   |    |    |    | ['Alert TimeHeader', 'Alert Time', 'Header5']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Alert Time", control_type="Header")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Header - 'Trade'    (L501, T198, R601, B219)
   |    |    |    | ['Trade', 'Header6', 'TradeHeader']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Trade", control_type="Header")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Header - 'Chart'    (L601, T198, R701, B219)
   |    |    |    | ['Chart', 'Header7', 'ChartHeader']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Chart", control_type="Header")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Header - 'Settings'    (L701, T198, R801, B219)
   |    |    |    | ['SettingsHeader', 'Settings', 'Header8']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Settings", control_type="Header")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Custom - 'Row 0'    (L1, T219, R1919, B244)
   |    |    | ['Custom2', 'Row 0Custom', 'Row 0']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Row 0", control_type="Custom")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Trade Time Row 0'    (L1, T219, R101, B244)
   |    |    |    | ['Trade Time Row 0', 'DataItem', 'DataItem0', 'DataItem1', 'Trade Time Row 0DataItem']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Trade Time Row 0", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Symbol Row 0'    (L101, T219, R201, B244)
   |    |    |    | ['Symbol Row 0', 'Symbol Row 0DataItem', 'DataItem2']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Symbol Row 0", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Last Row 0'    (L201, T219, R301, B244)
   |    |    |    | ['DataItem3', 'Last Row 0DataItem', 'Last Row 0']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Last Row 0", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Volume Row 0'    (L301, T219, R401, B244)
   |    |    |    | ['Volume Row 0DataItem', 'DataItem4', 'Volume Row 0']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Volume Row 0", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Alert Time Row 0'    (L401, T219, R501, B244)
   |    |    |    | ['Alert Time Row 0DataItem', 'DataItem5', 'Alert Time Row 0']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Alert Time Row 0", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Trade Row 0'    (L501, T219, R601, B244)
   |    |    |    | ['Trade Row 0DataItem', 'Trade Row 0', 'DataItem6']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Trade Row 0", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Chart Row 0'    (L601, T219, R701, B244)
   |    |    |    | ['Chart Row 0DataItem', 'DataItem7', 'Chart Row 0']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Chart Row 0", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Settings Row 0'    (L701, T219, R801, B244)
   |    |    |    | ['Settings Row 0DataItem', 'Settings Row 0', 'DataItem8']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Settings Row 0", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Custom - 'Row 1'    (L1, T244, R1919, B269)
   |    |    | ['Row 1', 'Row 1Custom', 'Custom3']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Row 1", control_type="Custom")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Trade Time Row 1'    (L1, T244, R101, B269)
   |    |    |    | ['Trade Time Row 1', 'DataItem9', 'Trade Time Row 1DataItem']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Trade Time Row 1", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Symbol Row 1'    (L101, T244, R201, B269)
   |    |    |    | ['Symbol Row 1', 'DataItem10', 'Symbol Row 1DataItem']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Symbol Row 1", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Last Row 1'    (L201, T244, R301, B269)
   |    |    |    | ['Last Row 1', 'DataItem11', 'Last Row 1DataItem']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Last Row 1", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Volume Row 1'    (L301, T244, R401, B269)
   |    |    |    | ['Volume Row 1DataItem', 'Volume Row 1', 'DataItem12']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Volume Row 1", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Alert Time Row 1'    (L401, T244, R501, B269)
   |    |    |    | ['DataItem13', 'Alert Time Row 1', 'Alert Time Row 1DataItem']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Alert Time Row 1", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Trade Row 1'    (L501, T244, R601, B269)
   |    |    |    | ['DataItem14', 'Trade Row 1DataItem', 'Trade Row 1']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Trade Row 1", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Chart Row 1'    (L601, T244, R701, B269)
   |    |    |    | ['DataItem15', 'Chart Row 1DataItem', 'Chart Row 1']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Chart Row 1", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Settings Row 1'    (L701, T244, R801, B269)
   |    |    |    | ['Settings Row 1DataItem', 'DataItem16', 'Settings Row 1']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Settings Row 1", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Custom - 'Row 2'    (L1, T269, R1919, B294)
   |    |    | ['Row 2', 'Row 2Custom', 'Custom4']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Row 2", control_type="Custom")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Trade Time Row 2'    (L1, T269, R101, B294)
   |    |    |    | ['DataItem17', 'Trade Time Row 2', 'Trade Time Row 2DataItem']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Trade Time Row 2", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Symbol Row 2'    (L101, T269, R201, B294)
   |    |    |    | ['Symbol Row 2', 'DataItem18', 'Symbol Row 2DataItem']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Symbol Row 2", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Last Row 2'    (L201, T269, R301, B294)
   |    |    |    | ['Last Row 2', 'DataItem19', 'Last Row 2DataItem']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Last Row 2", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Volume Row 2'    (L301, T269, R401, B294)
   |    |    |    | ['Volume Row 2DataItem', 'DataItem20', 'Volume Row 2']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Volume Row 2", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Alert Time Row 2'    (L401, T269, R501, B294)
   |    |    |    | ['Alert Time Row 2DataItem', 'DataItem21', 'Alert Time Row 2']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Alert Time Row 2", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Trade Row 2'    (L501, T269, R601, B294)
   |    |    |    | ['DataItem22', 'Trade Row 2DataItem', 'Trade Row 2']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Trade Row 2", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Chart Row 2'    (L601, T269, R701, B294)
   |    |    |    | ['Chart Row 2DataItem', 'Chart Row 2', 'DataItem23']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Chart Row 2", control_type="DataItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | DataItem - 'Settings Row 2'    (L701, T269, R801, B294)
   |    |    |    | ['DataItem24', 'Settings Row 2', 'Settings Row 2DataItem']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Settings Row 2", control_type="DataItem")
   |    | 
   |    | Pane - 'Scanner Settings'    (L3, T29, R361, B166)
   |    | ['Pane2', 'Scanner SettingsPane', 'Scanner Settings']
   |    | child_window(title="Scanner Settings", auto_id="grpSaveLoadScanner", control_type="Pane")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Button - 'Edit Script'    (L23, T117, R107, B142)
   |    |    | ['Button', 'Edit ScriptButton', 'Button1', 'Button0', 'Edit Script']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Edit Script", auto_id="nEditButton", control_type="Button")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Button - 'Stop'    (L138, T117, R222, B142)
   |    |    | ['Button2', 'Stop', 'StopButton']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Stop", auto_id="nLoadButton", control_type="Button")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Button - 'Delete'    (L258, T117, R342, B142)
   |    |    | ['Button3', 'Delete', 'DeleteButton']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Delete", auto_id="cmdDelete", control_type="Button")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Pane - 'nuiPanel1'    (L4, T51, R360, B165)
   |    |    | ['nuiPanel1Pane', 'Pane3', 'nuiPanel1']
   |    |    | child_window(title="nuiPanel1", auto_id="nuiPanel1", control_type="Pane")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Pane - 'PravinsSignalAPP'    (L129, T66, R295, B91)
   |    |    |    | ['PravinsSignalAPPPane', 'PravinsSignalAPP', 'Pane4']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="PravinsSignalAPP", auto_id="cboScanners", control_type="Pane")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Pane - 'Scanner Name'    (L26, T72, R100, B85)
   |    |    |    | ['Scanner NamePane', 'Scanner Name', 'Pane5']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Scanner Name", auto_id="scannerNameLabel", control_type="Pane")
   |    | 
   |    | Button - 'New Scanner'    (L390, T85, R487, B110)
   |    | ['Button4', 'New Scanner', 'New ScannerButton']
   |    | child_window(title="New Scanner", auto_id="cmdScanner", control_type="Button")
   | 
   | TitleBar - 'None'    (L16, T-5, R1920, B23)
   | ['2', 'TitleBar']

   |    | 
   |    | Menu - 'System'    (L0, T0, R22, B22)
   |    | ['System', 'System1', 'Menu', 'System0', 'SystemMenu']
   |    | child_window(title="System", auto_id="MenuBar", control_type="MenuBar")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | MenuItem - 'System'    (L0, T0, R22, B22)
   |    |    | ['SystemMenuItem', 'MenuItem', 'System2']
   |    |    | child_window(title="System", control_type="MenuItem")
   |    | 
   |    | Button - 'Minimize'    (L1779, T0, R1826, B22)
   |    | ['MinimizeButton', 'Button5', 'Minimize']
   |    | child_window(title="Minimize", control_type="Button")
   |    | 
   |    | Button - 'Restore'    (L1826, T0, R1872, B22)
   |    | ['Button6', 'Restore', 'RestoreButton']
   |    | child_window(title="Restore", control_type="Button")
   |    | 
   |    | Button - 'Close'    (L1872, T0, R1919, B22)
   |    | ['Close', 'CloseButton', 'Button7']
   |    | child_window(title="Close", control_type="Button")
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make sure every parent element is found. When you create WindowSpecification, it doesn't actually find any elements. You have to call particular method to force searching the element or explicit call to `.wrapper_object()` method which can be omitted for production. For your example:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title = 'Scanner: PravinsSignalAPP')
dlg_spec = app.window(title='Scanner: PravinsSignalAPP')
print('dlg_spec wrapper:', dlg_spec.wrapper_object())

dlg1 = dlg_spec.child_window(auto_id="ctlScanner")
print('dlg1 wrapper:', dlg1.wrapper_object())

dlg2 = dlg1.child_window(title="DataGridView")
print('dlg2 wrapper:', dlg2.wrapper_object())

dlg3 = dlg2.child_window(title="Row 0")
print('dlg3 wrapper:', dlg3.wrapper_object())

dlg4 = dlg3.child_window(title="Trade Time Row 0", control_type="DataItem")
print('dlg4 wrapper:', dlg4.wrapper_object())

#dlg_spec.set_focus()
dlg4.set_focus()
```

Also properties `HasKeyboardFocus` and `IsKeyboardFocusable` are relevant to pywinauto's method `.set_keyboard_focus()`. `.set_focus()` just makes the window active.

---

UPD: the mistake was in property name, it should be `auto_id="ctlScanner"`.

Comment: When I run print('dlg1 wrapper:', dlg1.wrapper_object()) , this is the output that I get: ElementNotFoundError: {'parent': <pywinauto.uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo object at 0x000001F08DC35D30>, 'backend': 'uia', 'top_level_only': False, 'title': 'ctlScanner'} Does it mean that this element cannot be automated ? (I have updated the main question to include the output of print (dlg_spec.print_control_identifiers()) ) Basically what I am trying to do is extract the information from Row 0, Row 1 and Row 2. Do you have any examples/tutorials for WinForms & WPF using Pywinauto ? Thanks.

Comment: It's failed because the correct propery is `auto_id` as listed in a controls dump. Byt you use `title=` instead of `auto_id=`. To avoid confusion it's easy to copy-paste this from `print_control_identifiers()` output to window specification in your code. That's why we print `child_window(...)` in the dump as well. We added it very recently.

Comment: I've updated the answer with this correction. Hope it works.

Comment: Thank You So Much. It works. And using the output from `print_control_identifiers()` in the program is better than using Inspect. Thanks Again